# modalInstance is undefined in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

ModalInstance data is getting NULL in importing controller.
I have changed modelInstance name also.But dint work out.
here am adding my code,

**SaveController.js**

```
scope.open = function (_data) {   //data is present 
    var modalInstanceData = modal.open({
      controller: "PopUpController",
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        resolve: {
            data: function()
            {
                return _data; // values are present here
            }
            }
         });

};
```

**PopUpController.js**

```
angular.module('user').controller('PopUpController',
    ['$scope','$state','$uibModalInstance',
     function(scope,state,modalInstanceData,data) {

        data={};
        scope.data = data;   
        farmBid.produceValue = scope.data.produceId; //value is present here

    }])
```

**Html**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

                <div class="modal-body">
   <input type="text" name="produceValue" ng-model="farmBid.produceValue" />

   <!-- But here its not prefilling the data-->

   <input type="submit" ng-click="generate(farmBid)">
                </div>
 </script>

   Modal data values are not being visible in HTML page
```

Please help

Comment: You should make a habit of using same variable name as DI name...

Comment: yeah.. But even though i use same name here am not getting prefilled value

Comment: same name doesn't matter actually, it all depends on the sequence in both array. But I'm saying you should name them the same for ease of reading and maintenance. Almost all angularjs developer would expect them to be the same.

Comment: actually i dont want entire data to be passed to server. So i took another name for passing only two values.

Comment: I mean it should be matching like this: `['$scope','$state','$uibModalInstance','data'
     function($scope,$state,$uibModalInstance,data)`

Comment: Ohh yeah.. I will definetly take your feedback and will apply those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the parameters in right order and should match, you are missing **`'data'`**

```
angular.module('user').controller('PopUpController',
    ['$scope','$state','$uibModalInstance','data',
     function(scope,state,modalInstanceData,data) {
```

Comment: It was not letting me to accept untill 10min so...   I have a issue with this above edited code.Can you please check once

Comment: i dont get it, post a quesiton with details